# NAD 1983 UTM ZONE 10N or WGS 1984 UTM ZONE 10N?

Tags: coordinate-system

I calculate small acreages of areas in Sacramento, no larger than about 2 acres at a time. I need an accurate projection to measure by the T as I don't always have access to groundtruthing.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If you only need accuracy in measuring the acreage/area, then an equal area projection should be sufficient as it preserves the area of polygons.

Alternatively, if your study area is relative small, you can consider using [State Plane Coordinate System](http://www.conservation.ca.gov/cgs/information/geologic_mapping/state_plane) for California (Zone 2 for Sacramento).